# My java multi-thread (client-server) program throws a NullPointerException when socket object instance is created using the accept() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a multi-threaded client-server communication program that uses 2 threads to connect to multiple clients (but only 2 at a time).
The characteristics of the program are:

1. The clients can terminate the communication program from their side but the server thread does not exit.
2. The threads in the server do not close `ServerSocket` until the exit condition is fulfilled by the server program, i.e. the server keeps running continuously connecting to various clients if requested.
3. Every time a client terminates the program only the communication (related) streams are closed.

Now the problem is the line of code where the `Socket` object is created. After calling the `accept()` method of `ServerSocket` object, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Any insight as to where I am going wrong would be very helpful.

My Server side code:

```
 class Clientconnect implements Runnable
 {
   ServerSocket ss;
   Socket s;
   String n;
   int f;

   Clientconnect() throws Exception
   {
    new ServerSocket(776);
    new Socket();
   }

   public void run()
   {
    n = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    while(true) // thread iteration
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is ready to accept a 
             connection.....");

            s = ss.accept(); // ------**The NullPointerException occurs here**

            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has accepted a connection:\n----------");

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream (s.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader cl = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (s.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

            String in, out;

            ps.println("you are connected via thread "+n);

            ps.println("----------------------");

            while (true)
            {                   
                in = cl.readLine();
                if( in.equalsIgnoreCase("system_exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Client : "+in);

                System.out.print("Server "+n+" :");

                out = kb.readLine();

                ps.println(out);
            }
            s.close();
            ps.close();
            cl.close();
            System.out.print("do you want to close the server socket\n1:close\n2:continue\nenter");
            f = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
            if(f == 1)
            {
                ss.close();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
      }
  }
   }

   class test2g
   {
       public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
       {
           Clientconnect cc = new Clientconnect();  

           Thread t1 = new Thread (cc, "t1");
           Thread t2 = new Thread (cc, "t2");

           t1.start();
           t2.start();
       }
   }
```

It is a fairly simple communications program with no complex resource accessing or retrieval. I am running the client end on the same machine so it's "localhost".

My client side code is merely a reciprocation of the try{} block.

P.S. I have tried declaring the `ServerSocket` & `Socket` objects as static in the `Clientconnect` class but it did not help.

Comment: You never initialize `ss`, so it's `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `ss` needs to be assigned in the constructor:

```
   Clientconnect() throws Exception
   {
    ss = new ServerSocket(776);
    new Socket();  // Not needed because it creates a Socket that is immediately thrown away.
   }
```